# BigQuery conditional running sum

Tags: google-bigquery

Using SQL (Standard BigQuery), I need to calculate a running average of the most recent 4 weeks of sales in which flag was FALSE. The average is actually a baseline, so it does not include the current week's sales.

```
week    flag    sales
1       FALSE   3
2       FALSE   1
3       FALSE   3
4       FALSE   0
5       FALSE   3
6       FALSE   6
7       TRUE    3
8       TRUE    1
9       FALSE   3
10      FALSE   9
11      FALSE   6
12      FALSE   4
13      TRUE    4
14      TRUE    2
15      FALSE   1
```

For example, week 6 has (week2+week3+week+week5)/4=(1+3+0+3)/4=7/4=1.75.
For, say, week 10, the running average should not include week 7 and week 8 since flag is true. Week 10 should be (week4+week+5+week6+week9)/4=3

The whole table should like

```
week    avg
1       NULL
2       NULL
3       NULL
4       NULL
5       1.75
6       1.75
7       3
8       3
9       3
10      3
11      5.25
12      6
13      5.5
14      5.5
15      5.5
```

I've been trying to augment the answer here
[SQL Select Statement For Calculating A Running Average Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911326/sql-select-statement-for-calculating-a-running-average-column)

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT week,
  (SELECT IF(COUNT(1) = 4, AVG(sales), NULL) 
    FROM (
      SELECT sales FROM UNNEST(arr) WHERE NOT flag ORDER BY week DESC LIMIT 4
    ) 
  )
FROM (
  SELECT week, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(week, flag, sales)) OVER(win) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  WINDOW win AS (ORDER BY week ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
)
-- ORDER BY week
```