# Update row with average from another table based on the original row

Tags: mysql

Not sure how to describe what I'm trying to get from this question, but here goes...

I have a table of customer purchases, 't1', with information about the purchase: customer id, date, boolean if the customer was alone, and the purchase amount. In a second table `t2` is another list of the same customer ids with a date and a boolean saying whether they were alone.

I want to update the second table with the AVERAGE of values of the previous x purchases they did before that date with whether they were alone.

I setup the tables with:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;
CREATE TABLE t1 (cid INT, d DATE, i INT, v FLOAT);
INSERT INTO t1 (cid, d,i,v) VALUES (1,'2001-01-01', 0, 10);
INSERT INTO t1 (cid, d,i,v) VALUES  (1,'2001-01-02', 1, 20);
INSERT INTO t1 (cid, d,i,v) VALUES  (1,'2001-01-03', 1, 30);
INSERT INTO t1 (cid, d,i,v) VALUES  (1,'2001-01-04', 1, 40);
INSERT INTO t1 (cid, d,i,v) VALUES  (1,'2001-01-05', 0, 50);
INSERT INTO t1 (cid, d,i,v) VALUES  (1,'2001-01-06', 0, 60);
INSERT INTO t1 (cid, d,i,v) VALUES  (1,'2001-01-07', 0, 70);
INSERT INTO t1 (cid, d,i,v) VALUES  (1,'2001-01-08', 1, 80);
INSERT INTO t1 (cid, d,i,v) VALUES  (1,'2001-01-09', 0, 90);
INSERT INTO t1 (cid, d,i,v) VALUES  (2,'2001-01-04', 1, 35);
CREATE TABLE t2 (cid INT, d DATE, i INT, av2 FLOAT, av3 FLOAT);
INSERT INTO t2 (cid, d,i) VALUES  (1,'2001-01-07', 0);
INSERT INTO t2 (cid, d,i) VALUES  (1,'2001-01-08', 1);
INSERT INTO t2 (cid, d,i) VALUES  (2,'2001-01-08', 0);
INSERT INTO t2 (cid, d,i) VALUES  (2,'2001-01-09', 1);
```

`av2` and `av3` are the columns where i want the average of the last `2` or `3` transactions. So i need an update statement (two statements really, one for av2 and one for av3) to say "when this customer came in on this date, and they came in alone or not, what was the average of their last x purchases.

So the resulting data should be:

cid  d           i  av2  av3

---

1    2001-01-07  0  55   40
1    2001-01-08  1  35   40
2    2001-01-08  0  null null
2    2001-01-08  1  35   35

The closest I got was this:

```
UPDATE t2 SET av=(
SELECT AVG(tcol)
FROM (
SELECT v AS tcol FROM t1 LIMIT 2
) AS tt);
```

which seems to be going in the right direction (the limit 2 is the `2` or `3` from the av columns. But that just averages x prior purchases (regardless of customer or the boolean). As soon as I put in the WHERE clause to link the data, it chokes:

```
UPDATE t2 SET av=(
SELECT AVG(tcol)
FROM (
SELECT v AS tcol FROM t1 WHERE t1.d<t2.d and t1.i=t2.i LIMIT 2
) AS tt);
```

Any ideas? Is there a name for what I'm trying to do? Do I need to describe this differently? Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: It is called "moving average" or "rolling average". Two good solutions here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878473/how-do-i-calculate-a-moving-average-using-mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878473/how-do-i-calculate-a-moving-average-using-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SET @r = 0;
SET @cid = NULL;
SET @i = NULL;

UPDATE t2 JOIN (
  SELECT t.cid, t.d, t.i, AVG(IF(t.r < 3, t.v, NULL)) av2, AVG(IF(t.r < 4, t.v, NULL)) av3 FROM (
    SELECT t.*, IF(@cid = t.cid AND @i = t.i, @r := @r + 1, @r := 1) AS r, @cid := t.cid, @i := t.i FROM (
      SELECT t2.*, t1.v FROM t2
        JOIN t1
          ON t1.cid = t2.cid AND t1.d < t2.d AND t1.i = t2.i
      ORDER BY t2.cid, t2.i, t1.d DESC
      ) t
    ) t
  GROUP BY t.cid, t.i, t.d
  ) t
  ON t2.cid = t.cid AND t2.i = t.i AND t2.d = t.d
SET t2.av2 = t.av2, t2.av3 = t.av3;

SELECT * FROM t2;
+------+------------+------+------+------+
| cid  | d          | i    | av2  | av3  |
+------+------------+------+------+------+
|    1 | 2001-01-07 |    0 |   55 |   40 |
|    1 | 2001-01-08 |    1 |   35 |   30 |
|    2 | 2001-01-08 |    0 | NULL | NULL |
|    2 | 2001-01-09 |    1 |   35 |   35 |
+------+------------+------+------+------+
```

**Note:**
The value av3 for cid=1, d=2001-01-08, i=1 should be 30, rigth? ...not 40.

Comment: Wow, that is quite a statement. You're right though, it should be 30, not 40. I'll give it a try. One question, if I wanted to add another avg column, like avg5, is it enough to just put in another field in the first select like `AVG(IF(t.r < 6, t.v, NULL)) av5`?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, because `t`.`r` is a rank number of rows in a group.

Comment: Will it make a difference if `i` is an integer value instead of a boolean? The comparison is still `=`, but I changed the query upa  it and it seems to be doing an average of all values now (not respecting the `t.r` constraint). Trying to figure out what I changed that caused the problem...

Comment: >`Will it make a difference if i is an integer value instead of a boolean?` The data type of field `i` is integer (CREATE TABLE t1 (cid INT, d DATE, i INT...).