# SQL - Calculating variable moving average over variable lenghts

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

FIRST: This question is NOT a duplicate. I have asked this on here already and it was closed as a duplicate. While it is similar to other threads on stackoverflow, it is actually far more complex. Please read the post before assuming it is a duplicate:

I am trying to calculate variable moving averages crossover with variable dates.

That is: I want to prompt the user for 3 values and 1 option. The input is through a web front end so I can build/edit the query based on input or have multiple queries if needed.

```
X = 1st moving average term  (N day moving average. Any number 1-N)
Y = 2nd moving average term. (N day moving average. Any number 1-N)
Z = Amount of days back from present to search for the occurance of:
option = Over/Under: (> or <. X passing over Y, or X passing Under Y)


X day moving average passing over OR under Y day moving average
within the past Z days.
```

My database is structured:

**tbl_daily_data**

```
id
stock_id
date
adj_close
```

And:

**tbl_stocks**

```
stock_id
symbol
```

I have a btree index on:

```
daily_data(stock_id, date, adj_close)

stock_id
```

I am stuck on this query and having a lot of trouble writing it. If the variables were fixed it would seem trivial but because X, Y, Z are all 100% independent of each other (could look, for example for 5 day moving average within the past 100 days, or 100 day moving average within the past 5) I am having a lot of trouble coding it.

Please help! :(

Edit: I've been told some more context might be helpful?

We are creating an open stock analytic system where users can perform trend analysis. I have a database containing 3500 stocks and their price histories going back to 1970.

This query will be running every day in order to find stocks that match certain criteria
for example:

> 10 day moving average crossing over 20 day moving average within 5
>   days
>
> 20 day crossing UNDER 10 day moving average within 5 days
>
> 55 day crossing UNDER 22 day moving average within 100 days

But each user may be interested in a different analysis so I cannot just store the moving average with each row, it must be calculated.

Comment: Any chance you could post a small data set and the output you want from the query under a couple of set of params?

Comment: Sure, Coming right up...

Sample data: http://zbt-psu.org/daily_data.zip

Comment: Edited the above question with some parameters. Output = For each/every stock that meets the input parameters: The stock's symbol, The two calculated moving averages and the stock's symbol. Outputting the daily price history for each stocks over the selected period would be nice too but thats a bell and whistle that is not required.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I fully understand the question ... but something like this might help you get where you need to go: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b577/17)

```
SET @X:=5;
SET @Y:=3;
set @Z:=25;
set @option:='under';

select * from ( 

SELECT stock_id,
datediff(current_date(), date) days_ago, 
     adj_close,
     (
     SELECT
          AVG(adj_close) AS moving_average
     FROM
          tbl_daily_data T2
     WHERE
          (
               SELECT
                    COUNT(*)
               FROM
                    tbl_daily_data T3
               WHERE
                    date BETWEEN T2.date AND T1.date
          ) BETWEEN 1 AND @X
     ) move_av_1,
    (
     SELECT
          AVG(adj_close) AS moving_average
     FROM
          tbl_daily_data T2
     WHERE
          (
               SELECT
                    COUNT(*)
               FROM
                    tbl_daily_data T3
               WHERE
                    date BETWEEN T2.date AND T1.date
          ) BETWEEN 1 AND @Y
     ) move_av_2

FROM
     tbl_daily_data T1

where   
datediff(current_date(), date) <= @z
) x
where 
  case when @option ='over'  and move_av_1 > move_av_2 then 1 else 0 end + 
  case when @option ='under' and move_av_2 > move_av_1 then 1 else 0 end  > 0
order by stock_id, days_ago
```

Based on answer by @Tom H here: [How do I calculate a moving average using MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878473/how-do-i-calculate-a-moving-average-using-mysql)

Comment: I don't understand the question either, but +1 for the attempt; it looks great to me.  My only suggestion would be to use the OP's parameter names (X,Y,Z, and option) to be more clear.

Comment: Ian: wow, nice work. This looks correct to me. However, I have attempted to run in 20 hours ago. It is still running....hah.

Comment: Ouch - lots of data I guess!  I presume you have date indexed ?

Comment: Okay so its now May 17th. The query has not yet completed. Yes it is indexed....lol

Gonna have to try and improve this...